# See List View - or Image titles- of Media Library when "Add Media" button is used

Tags: media, library

When using Add Media button, the Media Library only shows thumbnails. Is there a way to show the list view instead, or in addition to the thumbnail, show the image title? My client needs to drop images into posts based on the title of the image.

Comment: I was able to find this discussion, but my host will not allow me to modify the core files:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/204889/trying-to-add-filename-over-image-in-media-browser